# How do I decipher this callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, callback, array.prototype.map

Below is the code snippet in question. In particular I'm confused by the line with the .map() method.
I've never seen this shorthand syntax used with `.map()`or in any other context with callback functions. I can't find any resources on it. Is this JQuery? 'c' is not declared anywhere else in the code that I can find. is this the equivalent of `let catIDs = response.data.map((category) => category.id);` and if so how does 'it' know that c = category? Any help is appreciated. If it's not clear, I'm still early in my coding journey.

```
async function getCategoryIds() {
  // ask for 100 categories [most we can ask for], so we can pick random
  let response = await axios.get(`${BASE_API_URL}categories?count=100`);
  let catIds = response.data.map(c => c.id);
  return _.sampleSize(catIds, NUM_CATEGORIES);
}
```

```
let catIds = response.data.map(c => c.id);
```

For more context, It's used again throughout the script:

```
async function getCategory(catId) {
  let response = await axios.get(`${BASE_API_URL}category?id=${catId}`);
  let cat = response.data;
  let allClues = cat.clues;
  let randomClues = _.sampleSize(allClues, NUM_CLUES_PER_CAT);
  let clues = randomClues.map(c => ({
    question: c.question,
    answer: c.answer,
    showing: null,
  }));

  return { title: cat.title, clues };
}
```

I tried passing `c` into the console but not surprisingly it was undefined. Additionally I brushed up on callback function syntax and the `.map()` method with no luck.